# Why does this test_and_set function lead to deadlock?

Tags: c, multithreading, deadlock

I am using two threads to update a global variable. In order to achieve mutual exclusion I am using the `test_and_set` function. But this code is going to deadlock at some random point during execiution.
Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

int a = 0;
atomic_int lock = 0;

int test_and_set(int *lock)
{
    int l = *lock;
    *lock = 1;
    return l;
}

void *func(void * param)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        while(test_and_set(&lock));
        a++;
        lock = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t p1, p2;
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, func);
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL, func);
    
    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    pthread_join(p2, NULL);
    
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will deadlock sooner or later.

This is how:

1. Thread A will "get the lock" and be ready to execute `a++` and `lock = 0;`
2. Thread B takes over and executes `l = *lock;`. Since A has the lock `l` is now 1.
3. Thread A takes over and executes both `a++` and `lock = 0;`. This sets the lock to zero.
4. Thread B takes over and executes `*lock = 1;` and returns `l` that has the value 1.

Now it's a deadlock. The value of `lock` is 1. Thread A return 1 from `test_and_set` and will stay in the `while`. Thread B will start reading the lock but will always get a 1. There is no thread that will set the lock to zero. Bang...

Likewise you can create a situation where both threads gets "the lock" at the same time.

Long story short: You can't implement a lock like that.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set:

> In computer science, the test-and-set instruction is an instruction used to write 1 (set) to a memory location and return its old value as **a single atomic (i.e., non-interruptible) operation**.

You don't have "a single atomic operation". Therefore thread A above can execute step 3 between thread B executing step 2 and step 4.

If your processor has a test-and-set instruction, you can try with assembler code.

Note: In the "real" world, task switches do not happen aligned with C statements. A single C statement it typically realized as a number of machine instructions. A task switch can happen at any machine instruction. Still the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet figured where your deadlock is occurring but this is not the proper way to implement a lock of data shared by threads.  Suppose that `lock` is 0 and that both threads call `test_and_set` simultaneously.  They will both see that `lock` is 0 and will both set it to 1.  That 0 gets returned and so both threads think that they have the lock.

A mutex (short for "mutual exclusion") accomplishes what you're attempting here by ensuring that the fore-mentioned asynchronous mess can't happen.

When you call `pthread_mutex_lock` on a mutex, that function will not return until the calling thread has acquired the lock.  That means that any other thread calling `pthread_mutex_lock` will block until the first thread releases the mutex by calling `pthread_mutex_unlock`.

Here's how you should use the mutex.

```
int a = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void *func(void * param)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock):
        a++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t p1, p2;

    pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I want to synchronize without mutex (its an interview question). Could you please explain how mutex is implemented?

Comment: I believe that mutexes are implemented in the kernel.  I don't know the mechanics.

Comment: You could look at [spin locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock).

Comment: It looks like you've **almost** got a spin lock implemented in your original post.  However, you need the first two lines of `test_and_set` to happen atomically.

Comment: Look at `atomic_exchange` from `sdatomic.h`.

Comment: I understand your point, it could lead to a situation where both thread might acquire the lock, but I could not understand why it is going to deadlock. I tried to print the value of 'a' at every 100th loop count but after some time I dont see any print which I assume means it is in deadlock (or infinite while loop).

Comment: I didn't run into any deadlocks when running it.  However, I did notice that there are a few mistakes in your code.  First, you print the value of `b` but that variable doesn't exist.  Second, `test_and_set` takes an `int*` but you're passing a `atomic_int*`.  Third, `func` should return a value.  Fourth, `pthread_create` takes four arguments but you've only provided 3.